# How to fetch record in mysql ORDER BY user_id DESC AND created_date ASE

Tags: mysql

I am newbie to Mysql Can any one help me for this?

I need to fetch Mysql record ORDER BY User_ID DESC and ORDER BY Created_date ASC

Is  it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible you can run query like this `SELECT ------ ORDER BY User_ID DESC, CREATED DATE ASC`

Answer (score 1):

`ORDER BY` accepts a comma-separated list of columns. So, simply put `ORDER BY User_ID DESC, Created_date ASC`